# How to get this json object in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

so I want to get the first key element from this JSON using python 3.7 without knowing its name.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
   "intent":[
      {
         "confidence":0.99313362101529,
         "value":"sendmessage"
      }
   ],
   "wikipedia_search_query":[
      {
         "suggested":true,
         "confidence":0.93804001808167,
         "value":"message",
         "type":"value"
      }
   ],
   "messenger_recipient":[
      {
         "confidence":0.93138399364195,
         "value":"me",
         "type":"value"
      }
   ]
}
```

EDIT:
I want to compare the name of the first key like so:

```
if(jsonobj[0] == "wikipedia_search_query")
   dosomething()
```

Comment: You want the list mapped to `intent`? Keys aren't inherently ordered in a JSON object (though the serialization necessarily imposes *an* order).

Comment: That is, `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` are two different serializations of the same object.

Comment: So the question is: ignoring the keys, what identifies a value in this object as the value you want to retrieve?

Comment: @chepner I updated the question could you check if you will find a solution?

Comment: Again, there's no reason why "wikipedia_search_query" should appear in any particular position; just check if it is *a* key: `if "wikipedia_search_query" in json_object: do_soemthing()`.

Comment: If you are creating an object where the order matters, you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Python 3.6+ does maintain insertion order on dictionaries, there's no guarantee that your incoming JSON will be in the order you expect. That being said, if you can guarantee the insertion order, here's a working example.

```py
import json

js = """{
   "intent":[
      {
         "confidence":0.99313362101529,
         "value":"sendmessage"
      }
   ],
   "wikipedia_search_query":[
      {
         "suggested":true,
         "confidence":0.93804001808167,
         "value":"message",
         "type":"value"
      }
   ],
   "messenger_recipient":[
      {
         "confidence":0.93138399364195,
         "value":"me",
         "type":"value"
      }
   ]
}"""

json_data = json.loads(js)

first_key = next(iter(json_data))
first_value = json_data[next(iter(json_data))]

print(first_key)
print(first_value)
```

#### Output

```
intent
[{'confidence': 0.99313362101529, 'value': 'sendmessage'}]
```

Comment: **Note:** I would recommend just iterating over the dictionary to find the key you want in almost all cases.